# Global Variable that can be used with all team project in TFS collection

Tags: variables, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am looking for a way to store a global variable (password) that can be used with all Team Projects in our TFS collection.  This will be used in our build/release process.  Currently we are on TFS 2017.3 but plan on upgrading to Azure DevOps 2019 soon.

I've tried using the Library and variable groups in TFS, but these must be entered for each team project which we have over 200 of.

Comment: I agree with the answer below, but you could achieve something like that with yaml templates

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not out-of-the-box option like this.

There is a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365752/library-of-variable-and-task-group-shared-between.html) with a lot of up-votes, so I hope Microsoft will add this useful feature soon.

Answer (score 1):

After you upgrade to Azure DevOps server, you can use the [Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) to pull data from Azure Key Vault. You can have as many Vaults as you like and use in one or all Projects.

Answer (score 0):

This item has more than 450 upvotes in site, however it doesn't seem like under development/delivery so far. In comments of the feature request, there seems to be a solution for this problem. There is an extension by DesAzure which can be installed: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ABNAMRO-DES-AZURE.DES-Azure-Distribution-Tasks
Hope this helps